# PHP adds "<head/>" to any xml output

Tags: php, html, xml

Not sure whats going on but here is my code:

```
$template = '
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <categories>
    <category>
    </category>
  </categories>';
echo $template;
```

But this is what comes out on the web browser

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<head/><categories>
  <category>
  </category>
</categories>
```

And when I change the code slightly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
categories>
  <head/><category>
  </category>
</categories>
```

Notice I removed the "<" and the head then attached itself to the next "<". What on earth is going on here? Anyone know what this is?

Comment: so that is the result but what about the code that does it?

Comment: Its the first thing I posted

Comment: R U Showing us the view source of the page, or what the browser renders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you setting the content type header properly before outputting the content in the browser? if not, browser will default to `text/html` and will probably add the header tag to it (not sure about this though).

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

and if the browser is not adding the tag, make sure that you don't output anything else than the xml in the response, maybe you are echoing the content after the html tag and the header has no closing tag (worth to check).

remember that headers must go before any other content, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: This is my guess. stevo hasn't mentioned how he's viewing the PHP script  output, but if you view it through FF/Chrome's element inspector you can see the HTML elements (e.g. `body`, `head`, etc.) that the browser adds to it to interpret the output as HTML.

Comment: I did try this but its not working either. I did a curl from the CLI just to make sure its not chrome or something and that "<head/> is still there. Also, I am viewing the source thats outputed in chrome and there are no <head><body> tags

Comment: Ah, you were right! My framework was ignoring the header flag. Thanks!